# APNS+PHP - Fails to deliver message for more than about 200 tokens

Tags: php, apple-push-notifications

I can send notifications to APNS for about first 200 device tokens in my database but after those the message get failed, Here is part of my log from my local server where the infliction occurs :

```
Processing #234: 153668daa0685d2cb988b6f4a1b5cc0d83ee52772.....<br>Message successfully delivered <br>
Processing #235: 9d9bbce1335de97fe06c4e82000008fad1b88337e.....<br>Message successfully delivered <br>
Processing #236: 74dc41e4e57fe492bdfbfdcda51ae73b217e3a72f.....<br>Message successfully delivered <br>
Processing #237: c8181554e6dc690d8e4a9ce32d1ea9d820d27045d.....<br>Message successfully delivered <br>
Processing #238: 86d86c9415f349647e1d428800dc3a78058775a16.....<br>Message successfully delivered <br>
Processing #239: a31437aa6a8a93ecf3443f2bdb8fa10e6f8c76b59.....<br>Message not delivered <br>
Processing #240: 99df796bc1c604db8adb9b43cb026d3afc97d6d99.....<br>Message not delivered <br>
Processing #241: 109cc26a1562962ec2f0817b9a87855cde3040462.....<br>Message not delivered <br>
Processing #242: 72dc77573e60cd689f05cb4c4b986f6ba8e1747a1.....<br>Message not delivered <br>
Processing #243: ecefedf21b5d08a922e7fec2798f8d08db89a9b43.....<br>Message not delivered <br>
Processing #244: d1d123bf2a3af135c18353a8ec80648b3d74e6231.....<br>Message not delivered <br>
```

I can verify that the device token #239 where the message starts to fail is valid token because I sent a message to and the message successfully delivered.

In my remote server I get a more explained error log which is:

```
Warning: fwrite(): SSL: Broken pipe in 
/myUsernameOnserver/public_html/path/to/file/push.php
on line 51 
Processing #32: d4fbb00733b13d41a2b6bba9f5c5eda14b21babd0.....
Message not delivered

Warning:  fwrite(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error 
messages:
error:1409F07F:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_PENDING:bad write retry in 
/myUsernameOnserver/public_html/path/to/file/push.php
on line 51
Processing #33: d77c5cb283646ed5f480....
Message not delivered <br>
```

My loop code for sending notification :

```
.....above:The connection and preparing of payload
// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

$i = 0;
//Send the Push to each token the close connection
foreach ($deviceTokens as $deviceToken) {
    // Build the binary notification
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

    // Send it to the server
    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

    echo 'Processing #'.$i.': '.$deviceToken.'<br>';
    $i++;
    if (!$result) {
        echo 'Message not delivered <br>' . PHP_EOL;
            //usleep(400000); //400 msec
        }
    else {
        echo 'Message successfully delivered <br>' . PHP_EOL;
        }
}


// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);

....End of function
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

### **The right code according to @Nick answer**

```
//Move the connection to a separated function
//to reconnect again easily in case of failing
$fp = connectToAPNS($directory, $passphrase);

$i = 0; //Logging counter

//Send the Push to each token the close connection
foreach ($deviceTokens as $deviceToken) {
        // Build the binary notification
        $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

        for ($k = 0 ; $k < 2 ;$k++) { //Number of tries in case of connection interruption
            // Send it to the server
            $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

            echo 'Processing #'.$i.': '.$deviceToken.'<br>';
            $i++;
            if (!$result) {
                echo 'Message not delivered at k='.$k.'<br>' . PHP_EOL;
                fclose($fp);
                $fp = connectToAPNS($directory, $passphrase);
            }
            else {
                echo 'Message successfully delivered at k='.$k.'<br>' . PHP_EOL;
                break; //Stop trying 
            }
        }

    }


    // Close the connection to the server
    fclose($fp);
```

My log is now :

```
Processing #284: 750e27148b65651f09bccf6617f93c7e8...<br>Message successfully delivered at k=0<br>
Processing #285: 2cdc924bdf8bc786bcc17877a324c79f1...<br>Message successfully delivered at k=0<br>
Processing #286: 48c298ffb890cd2f39e97b4214cb3d42f...<br>Message not delivered at k=0<br>
Connected to APNS <br>
Processing #287: 48c298ffb890cd2f39e97b4214cb3d42f...<br>Message successfully delivered at k=1<br>
Processing #288: 0768350f28f9b7adf64bb97265803838c...<br>Message successfully delivered at k=0<br>
Processing #289: d104e5e51062c568839cc37b4525a024c...<br>Message successfully delivered at k=0<br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A connection to an APNS server can be severed for many reasons. When a write fails for any of these reasons, you must re-open the connection. You can try sending the message to the same token again but keep in mind that if it really is an invalid token, the connection will keep breaking.

In your loop, when a write fails, you move on to the next token without re-opening the connection to APNS; this will not work. Add some code to re-open the connection when failing. You can even add some code to figure out why the write failed in order to determine whether or not you should retry the current token or not. You can read my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183760/500-error-when-sending-a-lot-of-push-notifications-php/19806947#19806947) for some tips as well.

Comment: Many thanks @Nick , Everything looks good right now, I'll post the right code for my problem.